# How do you scroll Tabulator when editing fields with key navigation?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using Tabulator, if the table has a horizontal scroll, how can you scroll the off screen columns into view when navigating with tab (or other) key?

The JS Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gbvam5ck/3/ has columns off the screen. If you are editing Column 1, then use the tab key to start navigating across the columns, when you get the one off screen, they remain out of view even when focused. If there any way to get them to scroll into view when editing?

We tried `scrollToColumn` in the `cellEditing` callback and that will scroll, but also causes the cell to lose focus (https://jsfiddle.net/v70zu3mt/1/):

```js
cellEditing:function(cell){
    var col = cell.getColumn();                             
    table.scrollToColumn(col);      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work by doing Tab then >(right arrow).

Comment: Yes, hitting any key once an off screen cell has focus will move to it (and if it's any character key will add the it to the cell text), but it SHOULD move as the cells get the focus from just tabbing. Otherwise how do you know which of the many off screen cells you are going to land on when you hit the right arrow?

Comment: You will get the next one. Try it in you fiddle.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but it also actually puts the right arrow into the text of that field.  The navigation keys should just move the to field, not alter it. What you are seeing is that the tab key is not moving to the field (which it should) or altering it. Then your right arrow key is moving to the field (which the tab key should have already done) and alerting it. The goal here is to move to it BEFORE it's altered in any way.

Comment: Using FF and Tab then the keyboard -> key from the navigation pad not the > symbol I do not get anything added to the field.